# how to get all headings(Not Headers) in a page using NetOffice API?

Tags: c#, netoffice

how to get all headings(Not Headers) in a page using NetOffice API?

There is little documentation and I'm struggling to get headings text in a page/document. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

**Word Object Model** doesnt have anything to get Headings in a page. So obviously Netoffice can't do anything as well(Its just wrapper on those Object Models). There is [HeadingStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211976%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for Table of Contents and Table of Figures.

You have to iterate through the styles and see if the Heading styles are matching. By default the style for Headings in Word 2010 is "Heading 1" so iterate through Paragraphs and check its style.

Sample using VSTO - Change it for NetOffice

```
Range rangeToInspect = // Range that you need to inspect
Style refStyles;
        foreach (Paragraph para in rangeToInspect.Paragraphs)
        {
            refStyles = para.get_Style();
            if (refStyles != null)
            {
                if (refStyles.NameLocal.Contains("Heading 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //Do the stuff here with Heading
                }
            }
        }
```